# Aamazon Open Search Serverless

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am using AWS OpenSearch Serverless to create a collection. Within a collection I have created multiple indexes. How can I delete an index within a collection? I could not find any python SDK or API to delete an index within a collection.